# Prepare for segue function not loading new values

Tags: ios, swift, segue

The `statValue` attribute of my UIButton class has been updated since the segue was last called, but the segue still sends the old, original value. Is there a way to refresh the prepare function (below) so that it sends the new value?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "StatDetailSegue" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? StatDetailViewController,
            let index = (sender as? StatButton)?.buttonIndex,
            let sendVal = (sender as? StatButton)?.buttonValue,
            let sendUnit = (sender as? StatButton)?.buttonUnit,
            let sendTitle = (sender as? StatButton)?.detailTitle {
            destinationVC.statID = index
            destinationVC.statValue = sendVal
            destinationVC.statUnit = sendUnit
            destinationVC.statTitle = sendTitle
            print("Destination STATID: \(destinationVC.statID)")
            print("Destination value: \(destinationVC.statValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've actually never used `prepare(for segue:)` like this - calling the sender - but have you set a break point see if either it or your`(sender as? StatButton)?` is `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you debug the value of `statValue` in your `destinationVC` and check if it gets updated after the `destinationVC` is presented? Also, check the implementation of 'StatButton' class, maybe the `buttonValue` property is a lazily initialized property and initialized only once? That's why maybe you keep getting the first value that was assigned to the `buttonValue` always.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **StatButton** if you using in storyboard your buttons , then your button should inherit from **StatButton** instead of **UIButton** otherwise your code looks fine.